# javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: [LDAP: error code 32 - No Such Object]; remaining name 'dc=server,dc=lan,cn=admin'

Tags: java, ldap

Am new to LDAP and am trying to use it for authentication. But i keep on getting this error: 
Connection Successful.

```
[LDAP: error code 32 - No Such Object]
javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: [LDAP: error code 32 - No Such Object]; remaining name 'dc=server,dc=lan,cn=admin'
    at com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtx.mapErrorCode(LdapCtx.java:3112)
    at com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtx.processReturnCode(LdapCtx.java:3033)
    at com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtx.processReturnCode(LdapCtx.java:2840)
    at com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtx.searchAux(LdapCtx.java:1849)
    at com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtx.c_search(LdapCtx.java:1772)
    at com.sun.jndi.toolkit.ctx.ComponentDirContext.p_search(ComponentDirContext.java:386)
    at com.sun.jndi.toolkit.ctx.PartialCompositeDirContext.search(PartialCompositeDirContext.java:356)
    at com.sun.jndi.toolkit.ctx.PartialCompositeDirContext.search(PartialCompositeDirContext.java:339)
    at javax.naming.directory.InitialDirContext.search(InitialDirContext.java:267)
    at ldap.Fedora.one(Fedora.java:104)
    at ldap.Fedora.main(Fedora.java:67)
```

This is where i have reached so far:

```
    Hashtable<String, Object> env = new Hashtable<String, Object>();
    env.put(Context.INITIAL_CONTEXT_FACTORY, "com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtxFactory");
    env.put(Context.PROVIDER_URL, "ldap://localhost:389/dc=server,dc=lan");
    env.put(Context.SECURITY_AUTHENTICATION, "simple");
    env.put(Context.SECURITY_PRINCIPAL, "cn=admin,dc=server,dc=world");
    env.put(Context.SECURITY_CREDENTIALS, "william");

    DirContext context = null;

    NamingEnumeration namingEnumeration = null;
    try {
        context = new InitialDirContext(env);
        System.out.println("Connection Successful.");

        SearchControls controls = new SearchControls();
        controls.setSearchScope(SearchControls.SUBTREE_SCOPE);
        namingEnumeration = context.search("dc=server,dc=lan,cn=admin", "objectClass=posixGroup", controls);
        while (namingEnumeration.hasMore()) {
            SearchResult searchResult = (SearchResult) namingEnumeration.next();
            Attributes attributes = searchResult.getAttributes();
            Attribute attr = attributes.get("cn");
            String cn = (String) attr.get();
            System.out.println(" Person Common Name = " + cn);
        }

    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        e.printStackTrace();

    } catch (Throwable e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        if (namingEnumeration != null) {
            try {
                namingEnumeration.close();
            } catch (Exception e) {
            }
        }
        if (context != null) {
            try {
                context.close();
            } catch (Exception e) {
            }
        }


}
```

Answer (score 6):

The error message means that the object "dc=server,dc=lan,cn=admin" cannot be found.

Your search base should probably be "cn=admin,dc=server,dc=lan"

Comment: namingEnumeration = context.search("cn=admin,dc=server,dc=lan", "sAMAccountName=william", controls);                                                                                                     I have changed but still it doesnt work.  What does sAMAccountName represent, because errors seems to be originating from this point.

Comment: sAMAccountName is the windows logon name (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms677605%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). Do you still get the same error message or something different?

Comment: Then you are still using the wrong search base. According to your configuration above you could try `namingEnumeration = context.search("dc=server,dc=lan", "sAMAccountName=william", controls);` or `namingEnumeration = context.search("dc=server,dc=world", "sAMAccountName=william", controls);`

Answer (score 0):

For example
using https://www.forumsys.com/tutorials/integration-how-to/ldap/online-ldap-test-server/

if LDAP username is not valid set then also shows 32 error.

below are the properties for reference

- ldap.urls=ldap://ldap.forumsys.com:389/
- ldap.base.dn=cn=read-only-admin,dc=example,dc=com
- ldap.password=password
- ldap.username=*dc=example,dc=com*
- ldap.user.dn.pattern =uid={username},ou=scientists,dc=example,dc=com
- ldap.aut.domain=ashokParmar